# C-Program Determine the largest substring in a char array without 'e' or 'E'

Tags: c, string, string-length, longest-substring

I have a problem as stated in the title. Here more details.

My Problem is:

a) develop a C-function which gets a char array as input parameteter and which determines the largest substring in this char array without `'e'` `'E'`. Print the length of that substring.

b) write main function to test a) function. use `scanf("%[^\n]",...)` or a loop with `getchar()`

EX: input : "you are one."
.output : "you ar"
length: 6

Comment: But `We ar` has an `e` in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvement of answer form @ChartesL.:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char myStr[30];
    char *ptr;
    // read myStr from console
    ...
    char* delim = myStr;
    int longest = 0;
    char*longestSubStr = null;

    for(ptr=myStr; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++) 
    {  
       if(*ptr == 'e' || *ptr == 'E') 
       {
           int substrLength = ptr - delim;
           if(substrLength  > longest)
           {
               longest = substrLength;
               longestSubstr = delim;
           }
           delim = ptr+1;
       }      
    }
    // show longest length in longest
    // longest substring starts at longestSubStr, first 'longest' chars
    ...

    return 0;   
}
```

it remebers the *last delimiter* (either start of string, "e" or "E") and whenever a new delimiter is found, the length of the substring between two delimiters is calculated. Then determinest the longest of these lengths and remembers the longest substring found so far.

Comment: it print only the character after the final 'e' or 'E'

Comment: i understand the algorithm but i just started to learn 3 days ago. could you please to write the whole code completely. i'm very appreciated that. thank you.

Comment: how can i print out the substring and the length of it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is too basic to be answered her. Read any book about c to learn this.

Comment: i know, i use gets(myStr) to input. and printf("output %s," longestSubStr). printf(" %d", substrLength). to printout the longest substring and the length. But when i run "aeaae" the output is also "aeaae", and the length just count the character in front of the first 'e'

Comment: Yes. As notetd in the code snippet, your resulting string **starts at** `longestSubStr`. Find a way to print the first `longest` chars of this string only. Hint: you may use `strncpy()`

Answer (score 2):

If you use the string library function strtok the solution is very straight forward.  Using this function it pull the substrings out for you and then you just keep track of the longest one.

```
temp = strtok(input, "eE");
strcpy(best, temp);
bestLen = strlen(best);

while(temp = strtok(NULL, "eE")) {
    if(strlen(temp) > bestLen) {
        strcpy(best, temp);
        bestLen = strlen(best);
    }
}
printf("%s", best);
```

strtok will split your string every time there is an e or E and return that into your temp pointer.  You can then look at the temp value and see if it is long enough to be your new best length.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char myStr[30],Str[30];
char ch;
int i = 0, j=0;
gets(myStr);


while(myStr[j] != '\0'){  //Use this to determine any 'e' or 'E' inside the string
   if(myStr[j] == 'e' || myStr[j] == 'E'){
          j++;
          continue;
   } else{
          Str[i] = myStr[j];
          i++;
   }
   j++;
}
printf("%s  length:%d",Str,i--);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not determine **length**. And it works only for  the first substring before the first "e". Question sounds like it expects "4" for the string "1e1234e2".

Comment: Hmm. the example for input output. INPUT: asdqEasdade and the ouput shoulde be asdad. printf the length: 5. Could you help me Dr.Koch

Comment: The new one may be better.

Comment: some error of too many argument for getchar() ?. could you please check again.

Comment: I am sorry for that. (Done)